# How to display an image in Java from web?

Tags: java, image, jpanel

i have an URL image, and i want to display it in a panel. 
How can i do it ?

Comment: With the past few questions you've asked, is this homework by any chance?

Comment: No, i'm trying to learning java and sometimes i can't do something. Sorry for my "newbie" question.

Comment: No need to apologize, just wanting to make sure the theme of your past questions were regarding homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use the [`URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class to grab the image from the web, create your [`ImageIcon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) object and then add it onto your [`JPanel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html),

#### Code is untested, but should demonstrate what you need to do.

```
URL img = new URL("http://www.example.com/whatever.jpg");
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(img);
JLabel label = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add( label, BorderLayout.CENTER );
```